# Summarise ranks of each column after argsort

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a df with several "attributes" and scores for each attribute:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((5, 3)), columns=['speed', 'endurance', 'strength'])


      speed     endurance   strength
0   0.901001    0.531624    0.599738
1   0.302515    0.439233    0.143280
2   0.616964    0.984054    0.151714
3   0.681594    0.601456    0.655960
4   0.831605    0.742175    0.276892
```

Thus for each row I can list the primary, secondary and tertiary attribute based on the score, with `df.to_numpy().argsort()`.

I need to get a summary of the number of times each attribute achieved each position, eg:

```
position  speed endurance strength
primary        3    2   0
secondary      2    1   2
tertiary       0    2   3
```

(I calculated my expected output by hand so it might have errors, but hopefully the principle is clear.)

I think I could do this by `(np.argsort(arr)==0).sum()` for each of `[0, 1, 2]` but is there a simpler way?

Comment: Be careful: a single `argsort` does not actually provide a [ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking).  For example, `np.argsort([40, 30, 10, 20])` returns `[2, 3, 1, 0]`.  You get a ranking if you `argsort` *twice*, but there are more efficient methods.  Using a predefined ranking function, such as Pandas' `rank()` method, or [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) is probably the simplest way to ensure that the data is ranked correctly.

Comment: Didn't realise that. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) and [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
# names
d = {1:'primary',2:'secondary', 3:'tertiary'}

# ranks
s = df.rank(1, ascending=False).stack().map(d)

out = pd.crosstab(s, s.index.get_level_values(1)).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

output:

```
           endurance  speed  strength
primary            2      3         0
secondary          1      2         2
tertiary           2      0         3
```

Alternative format:

```
out = (pd.crosstab(s, s.index.get_level_values(1))
         .rename_axis(index='position', columns=None).reset_index()
       )
```

output:

```
    position  endurance  speed  strength
0    primary          2      3         0
1  secondary          1      2         2
2   tertiary          2      0         3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count `DataFrame` created from `argsort` with replace missing values to `0` and `rename` index values with change order or rows by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
d = {2:'primary',1:'secondary', 0:'tertiary'}
df = (pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().argsort(), columns=df.columns)
        .apply(pd.value_counts)
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .iloc[::-1]
        .rename(d))

print (df)
           speed  endurance  strength
primary        3          2         0
secondary      2          1         2
tertiary       0          2         3
```